# My clock in minecraft pi is lagging

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I'm trying to create a clock in python that runs in minecraft pi. It's functional apart from the fact that each minute, it updates the numbers on minecraft another half second later than it should. I'm pretty sure that python knows it's changed, it just hasn't sent the message to minecraft to change anything yet - this is very bad in the long run, as you can imagine! I honestly don't know what's causing the lag - is it the limitations of the Raspberry pi? I've checked my code for any rogue 'sleeps' and I can't find any. Any suggestions as to why it's gone wrong?
http://pastebin.com/XfUk5TmH

PS - it's a very large program - the better part of 1000 lines, so be warned..

Comment: I haven't yet attempted to run your program, but what comes to mind initially is that Minecraft Pi comes with another Digital Clock example written in Java. See `/opt/minecraft-pi/api/java/src-demos/pi/demo/DigitalClock.java`. Have you tried that out? If it works fine, then you have a path to narrow down and fix this in your implementation. If it shows the same problem, then at least this would rule out anything specific to the Python side including the Python socket library.